# OpenGL: VBO functions are not defined

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, opengl, vbo, sfml

I'm trying to use OpenGL VBO's, but the functions associated with their use, `glGenBuffersARB()` for instance, are all undefined.  Immediate mode functions are fine of course, it's only these.

I'm using VS2010, with the [SFML](http://www.sfml-dev.org/features.php) library.  One of the include headers in that library includes both `<GL/gl.h>` and `<GL/glu.h>`, and the executable is linked against `glu32.lib` and `opengl32.lib`

Why are only these functions missing, and how would I be able to include their use?

Comment: Just FYI: There's something inbetween VBOs and Immediate Mode: Simple Vertex Arrays. The required functions are readily available: glEnableClientState, glDisableClientState, glVertexPointer, glNormalPointer, glTexCoordPointer, glColorPointer, glDrawArrays, glDrawElements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

GLEW will define them, as will other GL extension libraries.

Information can be found here: http://www.opengl.org/resources/features/OGLextensions/

> Using an extension that includes new function call entry-points is harder in Win32 because you must first request the function pointer from the OpenGL ICD driver before you can call the OpenGL function.

GLEW does this for you.